# Configuring the jetty shipped with Solr

Tags: solr, jetty

How do I change the configuration for the Jetty that is shipped with Apache Solr? Where are the configuration files located? I want to restrict the IP address that can connect to that instance of Solr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thorough instructions here:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrJetty

Effectively, you get to decide where the config files live and what is contained in them.